# Получение значения индекса масива из названия input

Tags: javascript, html

Есть input с названием time[1604361600][1604419200] . Необходимо получить второй элемент, то есть 1604419200.

Какие есть идеи?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var str = 'time[1604361600][1604419200]';
console.log(parseInt(str.split('][')[1]));
```

Comment: Это хорошая идея спс. А может в js есть норм. инструменты для этого?

Comment: Можно регуляркой вытащить, а так отдельных инструментов для каждой задачи в js нет. Только общие методы